# Calling a bash script from the launchpad

Tags: bash, macos

I am looking for a way to call a bash script from the launchpad.

I have found out that if I call this script `Foo` and I put it in a `Foo.app/Contents/MacOS` folder I can use it either by clicking on `Foo.app` in the finder or by pulling `Foo.app` on the dock and click on it there.

However, if I put `Foo.app` in `/Applications` it does not show in my launchpad.

What is the way to go ?

Comment: The folder structure alone is probably not enough; have you also created an `Info.plist` file in `Foo.app/Contents` to describe the application?

Comment: Yes I fiddled with that too. Even created a sample application with XCode. To no avail.

Comment: If mklement0's method doesn't work, then try make an applescript that calls the bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap an applescript around your bash script which can basically create a .app bundle for you.

Comment: Specifically, when you first save your AppleScript from `Script Editor`, choose `Application` from the `File Format` list in the Save dialog, which creates an `.app` bundle.

Comment: Yeah hahah thanks @mklement0 don't have an access to a Mac right now so I'm not sure what the exact process was to save was a .app bundle